# I got value error from train test split method

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

This is my code

```
 X_train , X_test,  y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)
```

and this is what i got

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7, 5000]
```

I have no idea what happend and i tried to run it over and over and that's all i got

Comment: I hope this link will help you.. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/train-test-split-error-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-sam

Answer (score 0):

What shapes do your matrices have? Seems, that `X` and `y` have different lengths.
Check it with `print(X.shape, y.shape)`